# MediaElement AutoPlay = "False" bug

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

I'm parsing multiple audio file uri's from XML and binding them to MediaElement's Source property. I have eight buttons which trigger the audio files. When the AutoPlay property is set to True, everything works great. Each button triggers the right audio file. BUT since I don't want the audio to start playing as soon as the page loads I've set the AutoPlay to False. Now nothing works. The page loads but the buttons don't trigger the audio files. How can I solve this bug?

Code:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    string name = "C";

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        SetPlayerSource();
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }

    private void SetPlayerSource()
    {
        XDocument audioPlayer = XDocument.Load("Audio.xml");

        var aani = (from audio in audioPlayer.Descendants("Note")
                    where audio.Attribute("id").Value == name
                    select new AudioClass
                    {
                        Audio = (string)audio.Element("url").Value

                    }).SingleOrDefault();

        player.Source = new Uri(aani.Audio, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
    }


    private void C_Key_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var buttonName = (sender as Button).Name;
        var underscorePos = buttonName.IndexOf('_');
        name = buttonName.Substring(0, underscorePos);
        SetPlayerSource();
        player.Play();

    }

    private void D_Key_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var buttonName = (sender as Button).Name;
        var underscorePos = buttonName.IndexOf('_');
        name = buttonName.Substring(0, underscorePos);
        SetPlayerSource();
        player.Play();
    }
```

XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="41,-8,-17,8">
        <Button x:Name="C_key" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="220" Margin="8,0,0,8" Style="{StaticResource C}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75" Click="C_Key_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="D_key" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="220" Margin="87,0,0,8" Style="{StaticResource D}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75" Click="D_Key_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="E_key" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="220" Margin="166,0,0,8" Style="{StaticResource E}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75" Click="E_Key_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="F_key" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="220" Margin="245,0,0,8" Style="{StaticResource F}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75" d:LayoutOverrides="Width" Click="F_Key_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="G_key" Content="" Height="220" Margin="324,0,305,8" Style="{StaticResource G}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="G_Key_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="A_key" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="220" Margin="0,0,226,8" Style="{StaticResource A}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75" Click="A_Key_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="B_key" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="220" Margin="0,0,147,8" Style="{StaticResource B}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75" Click="B_Key_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="C2_key" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="220" Margin="0,0,68,8" Style="{StaticResource C2}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75" Click="C2_Key_Click"/>
        <MediaElement Height="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="8,6,0,0" Name="player" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" Source="{Binding Audio}" Volume="1" AutoPlay="False"/>
     </Grid>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.autoplay%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) you should set `AutoPlay` to `false` *before* setting the `Source` property.

As you are setting the `Source` in `SetPlayerSource` you could remove the setter from the XAML. Apart from that the code looks good.

However, I've just realised that you are calling `Play` straight after the call to `SetPlayerSource`. This won't have given your code time to actually load the media before trying to play it.

You need to call `Play` on the `MediaOpened` event.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I tried to place the AutoPlay = "false" before the Source property but I stil get the same result. It just won't play. I'll try the empty sound file method.

Comment: @AllanHaapalainen - the order of the properties in the XAML makes no difference. I meant remove the setting of `Source` from the XAML altogether. However, I've just seen the other answer, which is probably correct.

Comment: I did remove it from the XAML. I meant that I tried to set the AutoPlay before Source in the code.

Comment: Thanks for the "MediaOpened" tip, had forgotten about it and was wondering why Mp3MediaSource was playing MP3s only with AutoPlay. BTW, found that using AutoPlay=true and MediaElement's SetSource is faster than using AutoPlay=false and calling Stop, then Play at MediaOpened event (see http://zoomicon.wordpress.com/2014/11/18/gotcha-mediaelement-autoplay-faster-than-doing-play-at-mediaopened/ for sample code)

Comment: another thing that has bitten me for a long time and just fixed in ClipFlair Studio is that for MediaOpened/MediaEnded to fire the MediaElement (at least in Silverlight) has to be in the visual tree - http://zoomicon.wordpress.com/2014/11/18/gotcha-mediaelement-must-be-in-visual-tree-for-mediaopened-mediaended-to-be-fired/

Answer (score 3):

First, replace `Name=player` in the `MediaElement` with `x:Name=player`. That has sometimes caused issues with other controls.

If that doesn't work, you may be trying to call the `Play` method before the audio has finished loading. Instead, try handling the `MediaOpened` event and playing the file there.

```
private void player_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     player.Play();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying! I tried both of the methods above. Now the file is playing as soon as the page loads. I want the buttons to trigger the audio files. How do I get them to do that?

Comment: @AllanHaapalainen - After the first time it plays, do the buttons correctly trigger?

Comment: @AllanHaapalainen - Glad you got it sorted. As a quick explanation, the sound was playing on load because you have `SetPlayerSource()` in the `OnNavigatedTo` method. By using an empty sound, it's still being played but obviously there's nothing to hear.